# How to get the table dependencies from nhibernate metadata?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a rather large and complex NHibernate application.  I'll spare you the details of why, but we have custom tables that track the entities in our system, their backing table name, and dependency order (think simplified sys.tables).  this is used for various data publishing post-processing and the dependency order is key to knowing how to do batch publishing of the data.

Today, these tables are maintained by hand which is becoming very difficult to maintain.  I'm searching for a way to automate seeding these tables.  `ISessionFactoryImplementor.GetAllClassMetadata()` provides a great deal of rich info.  I'm sure I could write a function to interpret this on a property by property, association by association, and collection by collection fashion, but I'm hoping to find something already baked within NHibernate.  NHibernate obviously has this intelligence inside of itself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information you want is I think just the configuration data, tables, columns, FKs PKs etc right?

This can be found within the configuration object which is build during initialization of the session factory.

If you use FluentNHibernate, the configuration object can be returned from `Fluently.Configure()...ExposeConfiguration(cfg => ...)` for example...

This object contains all the information about all mapped classes `.ClassMappings` and collections `.CollectionMappings`. Whithin each mapping you have a property `Table` of type `NHibernate.Mapping.Table` which contains all the database related information like columns, references etc...

Let's have a small example which prints all table names with columns and FKs

```
foreach (var clazz in cfg.ClassMappings)
{
    Table table = clazz.Table;

    Console.WriteLine("Tablename: " + table.Name + " - Columns: " + string.Join(", ", table.ColumnIterator.Select(p => p.Name)));

    foreach (var uid in table.UniqueKeyIterator)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UniqueKey: " + string.Join(", ", uid.Columns.Select(p=>p.Name)));
    }

    foreach (var fk in table.ForeignKeyIterator)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FKs: " + string.Join(", ", fk.Columns.Select(p => p.Name)) + " - to table " + fk.ReferencedTable.Name);
    }
}
```

If you want to see more details of how this is used a good starting point is if you look into the code of `Configuration.GenerateSchemaCreationScript` method which is used by the `SchemaExport` implementation for example.

This should be enough for you to figure out the dependencies and order the list of tables for example...

Comment: You are right, this is all configuration and certainly information NH has (presumably in the Configuration and SessionFactory objects).  However, notice SchemaExport skirts this problem by always creating/droping FKs after the all tables have been dealt with.  So that code doesn't really help me.  I'm sure I could knock this out in a few hours but was really looking for a ready made sort function that is already doing this.

Comment: Looking at this closer, the ReferencedTable on the FK should make this trivial.  This will work better than IClassMetadata off the session factory.  Thanks